# Does $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to b^-$ mean $f(x)$ tends to infinity as $x$ approaches $b$ from the left hand side?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Feel like this should be obvious and something I should definitely know, but just wanted clarification to avoid a misunderstanding in my knowledge:

Does $x \to b^-$ mean $x$ approaches $b$ from the left hand side of the graph?

Any help in clearing up this gap in my knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is indeed exactly what's commonly meant by this notation.